# Random walk on cube with condition of not returning

Tags: probability, random-walk

> An ant is placed in a corner of a cube and cannot move. A spider starts from the opposite corner, and can move along the cube's edges in any direction (x,y,z) with equal probability 1/3. On average, how many steps will the spider need to get to the ant given that it will give up if it reaches back to its starting point at any point of time?

This question is similar to [Random walk on the edges of a cube](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139384/random-walk-on-the-edges-of-a-cube). How do I accommodate this condition into the equations?

This sort of suggests (0,0,0) being an absorbing state but I'm not sure how to tackle this question.

Comment: At what point [in this detailed answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/139683/919) does it first become unclear how to proceed?

Comment: The ant traverses the edge, with equal probability 1/3. In the flat plane, is "stay" a move? otherwise, it's up, down, left, right, upleft, upright, downleft, downright.

Comment: @whuber the solution you have shared does not include the condition that the spider gives up if it reaches 0,0,0 before reaching (1,1,1). Expected number of steps here will change here from the linked question because suppose 1 path is from (0,0,0) to (0,1,0) to (0,0,0). So we will be counting this in the linked answer but not here for calculating the expected steps.

Comment: If the ant gives up, does that make the expectation infinite? Or end the walk (so the walk is of length $2$ with probability $\frac13$)?

Comment: @Henry The question *appears* to concern a conditional expectation, so the expected length conditional on giving up would not be directly relevant to the answer.  But the ambiguous problem statement seems to permit several different reasonable interpretations: one has to decide what "give up" and "on average" are intended to mean.

Comment: @whuber if you take it as a conditional expectation, conditioned on reaching the ant (which has probability $0.4$), then the expected number of steps seems to be $4.6$. Note that this is less than half the expected number of steps if the spider never gives up.

Comment: @Henry please could you provide the solution for this answer you mentioned? 4.6 is the correct answer.

Comment: @Charlie Find the probability $p_n$ that the spider takes $N=n$ steps to first arrive at the ant without giving up.  Then find the conditional expectation $\dfrac{\sum n \,p_n}{\sum p_n} = \dfrac{1.84}{0.4}=4.6$